# Lack of Transparency & Communication

Tags: management, people-management

***Background***

Recently I've joined a Chinese company.
I joined this company because of the beneft's offered by the company.

I came from a very agile working environment. In my previous environment, we would have a Sprint planning and then team members would pull their task from the backlog in Jira.

In this new Chinese company, it's a totally different thing. I would say, still the waterfall style. Manager will just Skype or come to you verbally and ask you to do this and that if any task available.

***Problem***

I was under a 6 months probation, my manager didn't assigned me any task, and was frequently absent. A week ago was the end of my probation period. My evaluation was apparently based upon the opinion of a collegue who neither worked with me or formally reviewed my work, and was not positive. HR has talked to me about extending my probation. I can't lose this job, my parents need me.

After my review, my team was merged into a new team with a new manager.

***Question***

Should I **approach** the **new manager** and **discuss** with him my concerns, such as how can I help the team? Where can I get my task from etc..? Whats the process..

Comment: thanks for the edit to make the questions clearer @jmoreno

Comment: Do managers ever tell their team what the expectations are?

Comment: Hi @Jeff0, not at all.. the whole things makes me feel, the manager still a noob lol , no proper introduction etc..

Comment: @JeffO - Of course.  They let you know about every deadline as it's missed, and every requirement as it's kicked back by the stakeholders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy answer here because the problems may be part cultural, part company-specific and part your different experience.

That said, yes, I would talk to the new manager about two things. First, I would **talk about how task assignment and transparency works**. Assuming the new manager also sticks to the more waterfall or top-down way of assigning tasks, you probably cannot change this, at least not straight away. By all means, suggest improvements but, from experience, fighting against the system just hurts you.

Try to find a way to be productive. **Your productivity is your responsibility**, not your manager. If your manager is absent, try to help your peers or do some documentation. Focus on solving problems your manager cares about. Perception is important, so do not be afraid to talk about your achievements or how you have helped others.

Second, I would **talk about how you are to be judged and measured**. If what you say is correct and you were judged by a peer that did not work with you, it would probably be in both your and your manager's interests to have something more accurate. Agree on something more concrete beforehand (including who and what) so it does not come as a surprise later.

If all else fails, I do not know your personal situation but there are always other jobs out there. While it can be easy to think of leaving a company as failure, you may look back on this and be glad you left. It will be certainly an area you will want to ask interviewers about for future positions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply akton, i'm actually very sad about this for several days and didn't know where to look for advice until i came across this website.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Akton, i arranged a meetup with my manager a day after, although he didn't get back to me personally , but then he did address it in a group meeting

Comment: @Snooper Hopefully your manager addresses this to your satisfaction.

Comment: thanks he already did .. but then somehow in my mind keep thinking i can do better. I think he inspire me to be a manager lol .. i will try to apply for that position a month later